# MultiLine string inside String.Format()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, visual-studio, multiline

I'm trying to simplify some lines of code trying to assign a multiline string in the string.format method but it throws an exception at the "< / a >" characters it says "Expression expected":

```
Dim RegistryScript As String = String.Format(<![CDATA[
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
    "PATH"="{0}"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
    "PATH"="{1}"
]]></a>.Value, String.Join(";", PATH_Current), String.Join(";", PATH_Local))
```

So if I can't do that then maybe I can do something similar string trick?

This is the original code I want to make it more readable in code:

```
' Current user
IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath, " Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]" & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, String.Format("""PATH""=""{0}""", String.Join(";", PATH_Current)) & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)

' Local Machine
IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, " Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]" & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
IO.File.AppendAllText(FilePath, String.Format("""PATH""=""{0}""", String.Join(";", PATH_Local)) & Environment.NewLine, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)

Console.WriteLine(" [+] Backup done!")
```

I've tried too with a stringbuilder but I get a little bit unreadable code that's why I've tried to put them all in a multiline string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET doesn't support multiline strings, but you can simulate them with XML literals. However, your literal has to be valid XML. Either begin with an `<a>` tag, or leave off the `</a>` end-tag at the end.

Comment: Thankyou so much worked fine deleting the </a>, I've totally missed to put the beginning <a> tag to close the literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Dim multi As String = <![CDATA[
    Some
    multiline text
]]>.Value
```

Now you can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("multi{0} string = {1}", "line", multi))
```

Comment: Thats C# man, see my code it's VB.NET, also in your example you are assign a variable value not a parametter of String.Format(), anyway thanks...

Comment: @ElektroHacker That doesn't matter. Since `.Value` returns a string, the result of `.Value` can be passed as a parameter to `String.Format` which takes a string.

Comment: Note that `.Value` is a property, not a method, and thus doesn't require parentheses.

Comment: @Zev Spitz you saw and replyed to an edited version of the NullGeo code, When I said my comment is because NullGeo just putted the @ C# operator wich you know isn't in VB, thanks for read.

Comment: Sorry the question got edited while I was answering it. @ElektroHacker, why don't you store the registry text as a string resource and use it during runtime?

Comment: @NullGeo because I will edit some values in execution time, I think storing an "empty" registry file to take only the key names is not a good idea for me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make things easier on yourself.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader({path})
   sr.WriteLine("whatever")
   sr.writeLine("somemore on next line")
End Using
```